# loop excel sheets and rows in Python

Tags: python, excel

I have a simple code:

```
import xlrd  
book = xlrd.open_workbook('import.xls')  
for sheet in book.sheets():  
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):    
        print sheet.row(row)
```

but it's printing:

```
sheet1: row1  
sheet1: row2  
sheet1: row3  

sheet2: row1  
sheet2: row2   
sheet2: row3  
and etc
```

**I need to change this code to print this:**

```
sheet1: row1  
sheet2: row1  
sheet3: row1  

sheet1: row2  
sheet2: row2  
sheet3: row2  
and etc.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook('import.xls')

max_nb_row = 0
for sheet in book.sheets():
  max_nb_row = max(max_nb_row, sheet.nrows)

for row in range(max_nb_row) :
  for sheet in book.sheets() :
    if row < sheet.nrows :
      print sheet.row(row)
```